# extract ip address from variable string

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to create a bash script which will be able to change the "allow from" ip address in the phpmyadmin command file (which im still not sure is possible to do) and restart apache

I'm currently trying to extract an ip address from a variable and after searching the web I still have no clue, here is what I have so far...

```
#bash shell script
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "Get client IP address"
ip=$(last -i)
echo $ip

exit
echo "restart apache"
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

I've tried adding the following line with no luck

```
ip=$(head -n 1 $ip)
```

If anyone can tell me how I can extract the first instance of an IP address from the variables $ip I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: There are many IP addresses shown. How do you choose the one you like?

Comment: As mentioned I would like to get the first instance, so the first IP address from the list

Comment: Which Unix do you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ip=$(last -i | head -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
```

**Update:**

```
ip=$(last -i | grep -Pom 1 '[0-9.]{7,15}')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `grep` with `read`:

```
read ip < <(last -i | grep -o '[0-9]\+[.][0-9]\+[.][0-9]\+[.][0-9]\+')
read ip < <(last -i | grep -Eo '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+')
```

- `\b` may also be helpful there. Just not sure about its compatibility.

And yet another:

```
ip=$(last -i | gawk 'BEGIN { RS = "[ \t\n]"; FS = "." } /^([0-9]+[.]){3}[0-9]+$/ && ! rshift(or(or($1, $2), or($3, $4)), 8) { print ; exit; }')
```

Comment: Why using `read` and not a simple command substitution like that : `ip=$(last -i base | egrep -o '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+')` ?

Comment: Ah! indeed, it avoids the `head -1`, +1 for this solution :)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann `ip=$(last -i -1 | egrep -o '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+')` is actually the most ideal but @anubhava already gave the idea :)

Comment: Just a nitpick: `egrep` is deprecated (see `man grep`), use `grep -E` instead.

Comment: @terdon I see. I made the update. Despite being deprecated I doubt that those two `fgrep` and `egrep` would ever go obsolete though - since people would still continue using them inevitably.

Comment: Great solution, used in my answer too. :) +1

Answer (score 3):

To get the first instance you can just do:

```
ip=$(last -i -1 | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: `last -i -1` can still output multiple lines for one instance.  e.g.  date/time wtmp begins.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just do

```
ip=$(last -i -1 | grep -Po '(\d+\.){3}\d+')
```

The above uses `grep` with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which lets us use `\d` for digits. The regular expression looks for three repetitions of `[0-9]` followed by a dot (so, for example `123.45.123`), then another stretch of digits. The `-o` flag causes `grep` to only print the matching line.

This approach has the advantage of working even when the number of fields per line changes (as is often the case, for example with `system boot` as the 2nd field). However, it needs GNU grep so if you need a more portable solution, use [@konsolebox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24851512/1081936) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash only :

```
read -ra array < <(last -i)
ip="${array[2]}"
```

Or :

```
read -ra array < <(last -1 -i)
ip="${array[2]}"
```

Comment: `${array[4]}`? Did you mean `${array[2]}`? And how will this work when the number of fields changes? For example on `reboot` lines?

Comment: @terdon : Yes it's `${array[2]}`, i've corrected my answer ;)

Comment: @terdon : If the number of fields change, we have to adapt our command, as well as for solutions that use `awk` in this discussion (but the number of fields wouldn't change if the parsed command doesn't change) ;)

Comment: They do, have a look at the output. Try `last -i | grep reboot` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're a nitpicker (and have a grep with `-P`), you can test the next:

```
while read -r testline
do
    echo "input :=$testline="
    read ip < <(grep -oP '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))\b' <<< "$testline")
    echo "result:=${ip:=NOTFOUND}="
    echo
done <<EOF
some bla bla 127.0.0.1 some
10.10.10.10
bad one 300.200.300.400
some other bla 127.0.0.1 some another 10.1.1.0
10.10.10.10 10.1.1.0
bad one 300.200.300.400 and good 192.168.1.1

above is empty and no ip here too
EOF
```

It skips wrong ip adr, like `800.1.1.1` so, for the above test prints:

```
input :=some bla bla 127.0.0.1 some=
result:=127.0.0.1=

input :=10.10.10.10=
result:=10.10.10.10=

input :=bad one 300.200.300.400=
result:=NOTFOUND=

input :=some other bla 127.0.0.1 some another 10.1.1.0=
result:=127.0.0.1=

input :=10.10.10.10 10.1.1.0=
result:=10.10.10.10=

input :=bad one 300.200.300.400 and good 192.168.1.1=
result:=192.168.1.1=

input :==
result:=NOTFOUND=

input :=above is empty and no ip here too=
result:=NOTFOUND=
```

The `\b` is needed to skip matching an ip, like: 610.10.10.10, what is containing a valid ip (10.10.10.10).

The regex is taken from: https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net

Answer (score 0):

Since I happen to have needed to do something in the same ballpark, here is a basic regular expression and an extended regular expression to loosly match an IP address (v4) making sure that there are 4 sequences of 1-3 numbers delimited by a 3 '.'.

```
# Basic Regular Expression to loosly match an IP address:
bre_match_ip="[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}"

# Extended Regular Expression to loosly match an IP address:
ere_match_ip="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Of course when matching IP (v4) addresses from a file (say HTML) it's quite easy to inadvertently match a version string or an url which contains versioning as part of its file path. The following is some Awk code I wrote a while ago for use in a Bash script to extract valid unique (no duplicates) IP addresses from a file. It avoids version numbers whether in the text or as part of an url and makes sure the IP numbers are in range.

I appreciate that this is overkill for the original poster and that it is not tailored for his needs but someone doing a search may come across this answer and find the fairly comprehensive nature of the code useful. The Awk code is thankfully well commented as it uses some slightly obscure aspects of Awk that the casual Awk user would probably not be familiar with.

```
awkExtractIPAddresses='
BEGIN {
    # Regex to match an IP address like sequence (even if too long to be an IP).
    # This is deliberately a loose match, the END section will check for IP
    # address validity.
    ipLikeSequence = "[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[0-9.]*";

    # Regex to match a number sequence longer than 3 digits.
    digitSequenceTooLongNotIP = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+";

    # Regex to match an IP address like sequence which is a version number.
    # Equivalent to "(version|ver|v)[ .:]*" if "tolower($0)" was used.
    versioningNotIP = "[Vv]([Ee][Rr]([Ss][Ii][Oo][Nn])?)?[ .:]*" ipLikeSequence;

    # Regexes to match IP address like sequences next to forward slashes, to
    # avoid version numbers in urls: e.g. http://web.com/libs/1.6.1.0/file.js
    beginsWithFwdSlashNotIP = "[/]" ipLikeSequence;
    endsWithFwdSlashNotIP = ipLikeSequence "[/]";
}
{
    # Set line to the current line (more efficient than using $0 below).
    line = $0;

    # Replace sequences on line which will interfere with extracting genuine
    # IPs. Use a replacement char and not the empty string to avoid accidentally
    # creating a valid IP address from digits on either side of the removed
    # sections. Use "/" as the replacement char for the 2 "FwdSlash" regexes so
    # that multiple number dot slash sequences all get removed, as using "x"
    # could result in inadvertently leaving such a sequence in place.
    # e.g. "/lib1.6.1.0/1.2.3.4/5.6.7.8/file.js" leaves "/lib1.6.1.0xx/file.js"

    gsub(digitSequenceTooLongNotIP, "x", line);
    gsub(versioningNotIP, "x", line);
    gsub(beginsWithFwdSlashNotIP, "/", line);
    gsub(endsWithFwdSlashNotIP, "/", line);

    # Loop through the current line matching IP address like sequences and
    # storing them in the index of the array ipUniqueMatches. By using ipMatch
    # as the array index duplicates are avoided and the values can be easily
    # retrieved by the for loop in the END section. match() automatically sets
    # the built in variables RSTART and RLENGTH.

    while (match(line, ipLikeSequence))
    {
        ipMatch = substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        ipUniqueMatches[ipMatch];
        line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH + 1);
    }
}
END {
    # Define some IP address related constants.
    ipRangeMin = 0;
    ipRangeMax = 255;
    ipNumSegments = 4;
    ipDelimiter = ".";

    # Loop through the ipUniqueMatches array and print any valid IP addresses.
    # The awk "for each" type of loop is different from the norm. It provides
    # the indexes of the array and NOT the values of the array elements which
    # is more usual in this type of loop.

    for (ipMatch in ipUniqueMatches)
    {
        numSegments = split(ipMatch, ipSegments, ipDelimiter);
        if (numSegments == ipNumSegments &&
            ipSegments[1] >= ipRangeMin && ipSegments[1] <= ipRangeMax &&
            ipSegments[2] >= ipRangeMin && ipSegments[2] <= ipRangeMax &&
            ipSegments[3] >= ipRangeMin && ipSegments[3] <= ipRangeMax &&
            ipSegments[4] >= ipRangeMin && ipSegments[4] <= ipRangeMax)
        {
            print ipMatch;
        }
    }
}'

# Extract valid IP addresses from $fileName, they will each be separated
# by a new line.
awkValidIpAddresses=$(awk "$awkExtractIPAddresses" < "$fileName")
```

I hope this is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Awk.

```
ip=$(awk '{if(NR == 1) {print $3; exit;}}' < <(last -i))
```